# GOPATH not set correctly and cannot download

Tags: go

Initially the error happens when I want to install with go

```
sudo go get github.com/njasm/gosoundcloud
package github.com/njasm/gosoundcloud: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

But when I look for the GOPATH

```
echo $GOPATH
home/maker/go
```

I can also build scripts, what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `sudo`.

Your $GOPATH is pointing to your local use account.  So a guess is that you have $GOPATH set in your `.profile` or `.bashrc` file, meaning it is local to your user.

Go is meant to run within your user space, with no sudo for development.

so...

```
go get github.com/njasm/gosoundcloud
```

If you installed Go with `sudo apt-get install Go`, that's fine.  Just make sure your $GOPATH is set properly for your user, and run the command abve without sudo.

Now, if you are trying to install a binary (is gosoundcloud a binary?), then first build it under your account:

```
go install github.com/njasm/gosoundcloud
```

This puts the binary into `$GOPATH/bin`.  Then just cp it:

```
sudo cp /home/maker/go/bin/{binary name} /usr/bin
```

Or alike...

Comment: Thanks! But the reason I'm using sudo is because I got permission errors. package github.com/njasm/gosoundcloud: mkdir /home/maker/go/src/github.com: permission denied

Comment: chown -R username directory and chmod -R u+rX directory fixed it

Comment: Odd. perhaps you created that directory with `sudo mkdir ...`?